Передача данных client to client без сервера на C#/.NET?
Занимаюсь разработкой что-то типо мессенджера, и при разработки встал вопрос, возможно ли реализовать передачу данных между пользователями без участия серверной части.
На просторах интернета практически никакой информации, есть ли какие-то библиотеки или что-то вспомогающие для реализации на .NET, да и в целом как возможно реализовать данную задачу на C#
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно взять информацию

Ну как это нет инфы в интернете, просто наберите в поиске c# p2p messenger и там полно всякого: вот чей то github например. Главное понимать, что без сервера не обойтись, просто в этом случае каждый клиент еще и небольшой сервер, который тоже может принимать входящие сообщения. Ну и схема эта называется peer-to-peer или p2p, по этой теме куча материалов в инете есть.

Технология WebRTC создана именно для общения клиент-клиент. Но, как вам уже написали, сигнальный сервер всё равно нужен. / В дотнете для создания чатов и т. п. существует фреймворк SignalR. Пощупайте его.

Передачу данных между пользователями без участия сервера организовать можно. Пользователь - это такая же сторона обмена информацией, что и сервер.
Но проблема в том, как пользователям найти друг друга, как обменяться адресами. Вот для этого и понадобится сервер, и без него не обойтись.
Конечно, можно обменяться адресами с помощью других средств связи, например, электронной почты. Нужно учитывать, что при бессерверной архитектуре каждый пользователь должен иметь постоянный адрес - либо это статический IP-адрес, либо имя в DNS (но в этом случае у каждого пользователя должен быть свой маленький сервер).
